# Why does NSFileManager disagree with statfs about disk space remaining?

Tags: ios

I've tried two implementations on iOS 12 to get the remaining free disk space.

"The Apple Way"

```
uint64_t get_disk_bytes_free()
{
    uint64_t totalSpace = 0;
    uint64_t totalFreeSpace = 0;
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfFileSystemForPath:[paths lastObject] error: &error];

    if (dictionary)
    {
        NSNumber *fileSystemSizeInBytes = [dictionary objectForKey: NSFileSystemSize];
        NSNumber *freeFileSystemSizeInBytes = [dictionary objectForKey:NSFileSystemFreeSize];
        totalSpace = [fileSystemSizeInBytes unsignedLongLongValue];
        totalFreeSpace = [freeFileSystemSizeInBytes unsignedLongLongValue];
    }
    else
    {
        LOG_APP("Error Obtaining System Memory Info: Domain = %s, Code = %ld", [[error domain] UTF8String], (long)[error code]);
    }

    return totalFreeSpace;
}
```

"The Unix Way" - path is still the Library/Caches path.

```
struct statfs fs;
if(statfs(path.c_str(),&fs)==0)
{
    if(out_total_space) *out_total_space = (xu64) fs.f_bsize * (xu64) fs.f_blocks;
    if(out_free_space)  *out_free_space  = (xu64) fs.f_bsize * (xu64) fs.f_bfree ;
    return err_code_ok;
}
```

The Apple Way returns 4GB free. The Unix Way returns about 10GB free. They both equally report 16GB total (which is correct) but this device has hardly NOTHING on it. Just a couple of apps.

If I go to iPhone Storage in the Settings to see, it shows 11.8GB of 16GB used....almost all of it is used by "System" at the very bottom (8.65GB).

This System usage seems to disappear if i reboot the device but it comes back eventually.

Can someone tell me if there's any good reason for the discrepancy between these two methods? Which one is more reliable/accurate?

Comment: I am pretty sure that 4GB is the maximum memory one application can take. It's the available memory, not free memory.